# how to increase div height in all screens?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

Increase red box height with data and body and div margin be 20px in any screen size.
1920*1080 screen data is inside of red box but 1360*768 screens data is not inside of red box its overflow.

```
background-color: red;
border: 10px solid yellow;
margin: 20px;
height: calc(100vh - 62px);
```

[image]

Comment: maybe min-height instead of height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why letters are overflowed of div is that vh is 1 % of the height where currently showing. If height is set to 100vh then the height is 100% length of currenttly viewd screen. The example css is set to calc(100vh - 62px), which means is set to current viewed height - 62px. Even if screen size is set 1920 * 1080, too many letters to the example css are overflowed. [overflowwed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFjZK.png)

To make letters inside the tag I hope the tag is applyed with script.

```
<style>

    #test {

        background-color: red;

        border: 10px solid yellow;

        margin: 20px;

    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        put text here
    </div>
<script>
    //Get id
    let div = document.getElementById('test')
    //It's the height of whole screen
    let height1 = document.body.clientHeight

    div.style.height = height1 + 'px'
</script>
<body/>
```

Comment: vh: Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*